# Speed up slow Postgres query with window functions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to optimise a query, as the query generated by my ORM (Django) is causing timeouts. I've done everything possible within the ORM to run it as one query, so now I wanted to know if there are any Postgres tricks that can speed things up.

The database contains 1m+ and growing relationships (id, source and target) which I need to filter to exclude connections where the source doesn't appear at least 2 times.

This is the current query - and the list of "target" ids can grow which leads to exponential slowdowns.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
    "source",
    "target",
    count("id") OVER (PARTITION BY "source") AS "count_match"
FROM
    "database_name"
WHERE
    ("database_name"."target" IN (123, 456, 789))
) AS temp_data WHERE "temp_data"."count_match" >= 2
```

I've read about `VIEWS` and temporary `TABLES` but that seems like a lot of setup and tear-down for a one-off query.

### EDIT: Further info and tests on higher memory

**Result of `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`:**

```
Subquery Scan on alias_test  (cost=622312.29..728296.62 rows=1177604 width=24) (actual time=10245.731..18019.237 rows=1604749 loops=1)
  Filter: (alias_test.count_match >= 2)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2002738
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=622312.29..684136.48 rows=3532811 width=20) (actual time=10245.687..16887.428 rows=3607487 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=622312.29..631144.32 rows=3532811 width=20) (actual time=10245.630..12455.796 rows=3607487 loops=1)
              Sort Key: database_name.source
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 105792kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on database_name  (cost=60934.74..238076.96 rows=3532811 width=20) (actual time=352.529..1900.162 rows=3607487 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (target = ANY ('{5495502,80455548,10129504,2052517,11564026,1509187,1981101,1410001}'::bigint[]))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=33716
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on database_name_target_426d2f46_uniq  (cost=0.00..60051.54 rows=3532811 width=0) (actual time=336.457..336.457 rows=3607487 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (target = ANY ('{5495502,80455548,10129504,2052517,11564026,1509187,1981101,1410001}'::bigint[]))
Planning time: 0.288 ms
Execution time: 18318.194 ms
```

**Table structure:**

```
    Column     |           Type           |                                     Modifiers
---------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 created_date  | timestamp with time zone | not null
 modified_date | timestamp with time zone | not null
 id            | integer                  | not null default nextval('database_name_id_seq'::regclass)
 source        | bigint                   | not null
 target        | bigint                   | not null
 active        | boolean                  | not null
Indexes:
    "database_name_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "database_name_source_24c75675_uniq" btree (source)
    "database_name_target_426d2f46_uniq" btree (target)
```

**Hardware:**

I've tried increasing the server power to an 8GB memory instance and updated the `.conf` file with the following from PGTune:

```
max_connections = 10
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
work_mem = 209715kB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Despite the higher `work_mem` setting, it's still using a disk write for the merge which is confusing to me. Perhaps the window function is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I don't think I can, sorry - but I understand the request. Happy to take your advice and delete if it's not possible to answer without those. (The database was created by the ORM and all the data inserted that way also so I don't have that available. I'd be dropping into raw SQL just for this query.)

Comment: is target indexed?.. what is the cardinality of target column data?

Comment: you can run '\d <tablename>' in psql to look for table structure. And aslso please provide result of 'explain analyze select ....'

Comment: Thanks - have now added further detail. Table structure, result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE, and a test on more powerful hardware to test RAM increase. Any advice will be gratefully received :)

Comment: This looks like a *fat* bridge table. Is `{source,target}` *almost* unique? (they look like FKs into some (smaller) domain) Is `created_date` part of a candidate key? (and yes: the cardinalities, they could be important)

Comment: @joop not sure about the significance of "almost" but yes, each one is unique. It is essentially a map of many-to-many entity relationships, but it's the relationships themselves rather than the entities I'm focussed on collecting so decided to make the table manually and "cut out the middle man". Are you thinking that the query would be faster if I went another route and actually set these as FKs in the app framework?

Comment: Having a composite key on `{source,target}` and one on `{target, source}` could avoid the sort steps. Adding an extra column to these  almost-keys (one of the timestamps?) could even make them unique.

Comment: @joop would the query need to be updated to take advantage, or would these composites 'automatically' be used by the planner?

Comment: I had expected that a composite index would work, but it still doesn't, the queryplan is completely dominated by the `target IN (123, 456, 789)` selection, leaving no room for different plans. BTW : do you really *need* the count() aggregate in your final result? (the query could be rewritten into an `EXISTS()` form)

Comment: Followed the SO recommendation and moved over to a chat - [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144246/discussion-between-phil-sheard-and-joop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is already optimal. There is no way to avoid scanning the whole table to get the information you need, and a sequential scan is the best way to do that.

Make sure that `work_mem` is big enough that the aggregationcan be done in memory – you can set [`log_temp_files`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-TEMP-FILES) to monitor if temporary files are used (which makes things much slower).

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, that's helpful. I have tried increasing the RAM on the server instance as you're right, it was writing the merge to disk. Unfortunately it's not taking advantage of the increased `work_mem` setting despite being almost twice what's required. If you've got any insight on that, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, increase `work_mem` even more. The amount of memory required is way larger then the size of the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I've accepted your answer as correct as it helped me understand that the query was optimised as much as possible and either needed a more powerful (= more memory) server or for me to re-engineer the query. I can't justify the scale of server needed just now so I'm removing the lookup and pushing the work onto the client instead.

Comment: I stumbled on this answer after hitting my head against the wall for days and telling myself "Your query must not be optimized, make it faster". It turns out the `work_mem` was at 4MB and I was hitting the temp files